# PHP + MySQL Queue

Tags: php, mysql, queue, message-queue

I need a simple table that acts as a Queue.
My MySQL server restriction is I can't use InnoDB tables, only MyISAM.

Clients/workers will work at the same time and they will need to receive differents jobs each time.

My idea is to do the following (pseudo-code):

```
$job <- SELECT * FROM queue ORDER BY last_pop ASC LIMIT 1;
UPDATE queue SET last_pop WHERE id = $job->id
return $job
```

I had tried table lock and "GET_LOCK" but nothing happends, workers sometimes receives same jobs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**You need to turn your ordering around so there is no timing window.**

Consumer POP (each consumer has a unique $consumer_id)

```
Update queue 
set last_pop = '$consumer_id' 
where last_pop is null 
order by id limit 1;

$job = 
  Select * from queue 
  where last_pop = '$consumer_id' 
  order by id desc 
  limit 1;
```

Supplier PUSH

```
insert into queue 
  (id, last_pop, ...) 
values 
  (NULL, NULL, ...);
```

The queue is ordered in time by the id column and assigned upon POP by to the consumer_id.

Comment: +1 - I was going with a status field, but your idea was along the same of mine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this solution is wrong. There's a race condition between the UPDATE and the SELECT. Imagine you have two parallel requests running this code. What if this is the order it gets executed in:

**UPDATE 1, UPDATE 2, SELECT 1, SELECT 2**.

You will end up SELECTing the same exact row.

Comment: @OlegKikin, UPDATE2 cannot possibly collide with UPDATE1, as `last_pop` cannot be `NULL` after UPDATE1.

Comment: A failure after the `UPDATE` and before the `SELECT` will result in an orphaned item. `START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` are necessary to avoid that risk.

Comment: can someone kindly explain what the `last_pop` field contains? Also, is the `consumer_id` the unique code number for the worker?

Comment: @ethanpil, The last_pop field will be NULL until the item is claimed, and then will contain the unique consumer ID when selected for processing. There is no timing window because the select does not need to be coincident with the update.

Comment: Do you guys recommend that the consumer_id changes with each task run, so we can log individual tasks, or should each worker keep a consistent consumer_id, and maybe we also have a run_id in the log for each attempt?

Answer (score 1):

Just for information, there's another option that is using Gearman instead of a table to make the queue: [Rasmus Lerdorf wrote a very nice article about it](http://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/51-Playing-with-Gearman.html#extended).

Answer (score 0):

Oleg,

The solution is correct. `$consumer_id` must be a unique identifier for the processor. If you had a couple cron jobs on one machine, for example, you could use their `pid` as the `consumer ID` .

The UPDATE is atomic, so it marks exactly one row in the queue as being **consumed** by your `ID`.

For some applications I also have a status field for **finished**, so that if last_pop's `consumer_id` is set, but the finished flag is not set and the job is older than X, it can be marked to be restarted.