# PHP + MySQL Cycle Queue

Tags: php, mysql, queue, cycle

I just accepted a similar question ([PHP + MySQL Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690748/php-mysql-queue)), but I realized that it wasn't the correct question for my problem, but was the correct answer for my question :)

I have a MySQL (MyISAM type) table of sites to be scraped by workers.

```
CREATE TABLE `site` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `url` text,
  `last_pop` int(13) default NULL,
  `md5` varchar(32) default NULL,
  `disabled` tinyint(1) default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `md5` (`md5`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

What I need is to scrap one site per worker without repeat.
So, if I have 3 sites and 2 workers the system needs to work like this:

```
      ID URL   LAST_POP
t4    1  site1 t1         <- worker1 scrap site1
t4    2  site2 t2         <- worker2 scrap site2
t5    3  site3 t3         <- worker1 scrap site3
t6    1  site2 t4         <- worker2 scrap site2
t6    2  site1 t4         <- worker1 scrap site1
t7    3  site3 t5         <- worker2 scrap site3
....
```

It's like a cycled queue orderer by last_pop ASC.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to keep track of two pieces of information for each site: when it was last scraped and if it is currently being scraped.

Using the answer for your other question, set the `scraping` field to the id of the worker to lock it from other workers.  When the worker is finished with the task set the `scraping` field back to `null` and the `last_scrape` date to the current time.

```
CREATE TABLE `site` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `url` text,
  `last_scrape` TIMESTAMP,
  `scraping` tinyint(1) default NULL,
  `md5` varchar(32) default NULL,
  `disabled` tinyint(1) default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `md5` (`md5`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Lock and retrieve the next job (the site that was last scraped the longest time ago):

```
Update site
  set `scraping` = '$worker_id' 
  where `scraping` is null 
  order by `last_scrape` ASC limit 1;

$job = 
  Select * from site
  where `scraping` = '$worker_id'
```

Release job back to queue:

```
Update site
  set `scraping` = NULL,
  `last_scrape` = NOW()
  where `scraping` = '$worker_id';
```

Comment: you could potentially combine the use of the timestamp and scraping status, as long as their values won't conflict.  If you may have 100 workers, just select the job where `last_scape` > 101 and set `last_scrape` to the worker id up to 100 to specify it's being processed.  Make sure you initialize the field to a larger value as well, or they could appear already locked to all workers.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add an extra boolean column STATUS so that you can order by LAST_POP.  So when a site is selected by a worker for scrapping run a second query with `UPDATE site SET status = '1'`.  And when the next worker selects the next site run a query with `SELECT * FROM site WHERE status = '0' ORDER BY last_pop ASC`.